# Parallel actions in mergeMap with @ngrx?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have an Angular app with @ngrx and I'm using @effects to dispatch a few actions. Upon receiving a specific action I want to send some actions to read slices from localStorage.

```
@Effect()
  storage$ = this.actions$.ofType(LoadFromStorage).pipe(
    mergeMap(() => {
      return [
        new fromActions.LoadAFromStorage(),
        new fromActions.LoadBFromStorage(),
        new fromActions.LoadCFromStorage()
      ];
    })
  );
```

My question is, are those actions within mergeMap synchronous? I mean, are they sent at the same time and deal with asynchronously as if I was using forkJoin or Promise.all with promises? Or do they behave the same way as dispatch actions, synchronously?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `mergeMap` launch in parallel.
If you prefer in a sequence, you need `concatMap`

[doc is here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html)